# Adding an onclick event to a ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I'm trying to add onclick events to my tabitem that's encapsulated within my shell view but the events aren't firing.

I'm wondering how do I set a click event within the shell for a TabItem.

Generic.cs

```
<ContentPresenter Name="PART_TabbedFormPresenter" 
                  Content="{Binding TabbedForm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type shell:ActionScreenControl}}}"
                  DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type shell:ActionScreenControl}}}">
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>                                    
                    </Style>
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

My View

```
<Shell:ActionScreenControl.TabbedForm>
    <TabControl Name="Tabs">
        <TabItem Header="Summary" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick">
            <Grid> 
                <Panes:LoanSummary/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Shell:ActionScreenControl.TabbedForm>
```

I was wondering could I possibly add a trigger for the style to fire the click event.

Something like below

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Header" Value="Summary">
        <Click Event>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to implement a behaviour for the mouse down on a UI element, or what I usually end up doing is use something like these [Mouse Event Commands for MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/478643/Mouse-Event-Commands-for-MVVM)